# React JS google maps - Object is not a function

Tags: reactjs, function, google-maps-api-3, google-maps

I am just beginning to show the map but I am unable to move forward due to object is not a function error.

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleMap, withScriptjs, withGoogleMap } from "google-map-react";

function Map() {
  return (
   <GoogleMap 
   defaultZoom={10}
   defaultCenter={{lat: 95.9546456413, lng:76.365}}>
      {/* dummy lat lng */}
</GoogleMap>
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default function App(){
  return (
    <div>
      <WrappedMap></WrappedMap>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting this error. Didnt understand how to resolve it. Help please

[image: The error]

from console:

[image]

Comment: You're mixing up packages [google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) documentation is here. It looks like you're looking at documentation for [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/)

Comment: Great it works now. thanks. I changed it to react google maps in the import. I didnt understand it though. What object?

Comment: it's an error coming from webpack when you are trying to call a function (e.g. `withScriptjs` or `withGoogleMap`) this is not exported from a module.